# Adding a background image to JFrame using JLabel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, background-image, jlabel

I added a background image to a JFrame using a JLabel. But there are other JLabels in a panel added to the particular JFrame. After adding this background image all over the JFrame, other JLabels are not visible. How do I get them be visible?

Comment: Could you provide a [minmal, working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @Pahan Madusha You can consider not using JLabel to add background image. If I were you I would add it on a JPanel instead. Display the image on the JPanel. After that, add other components onto the JPanel. After that, add that JPanel into your JFrame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several options:

1. Make the JLabel opaque and make it the contentPane, giving it a decent layout, give it a decent `getPreferredSize()` override that makes sense in the context of your problem (JLabel's own override for this method won't work for you, since it depends on text and icons that the label holds and not on components added).
2. And then add other components to it -- to the JLabel.

Or:

1. Use a JPanel as the background image displayer
2. Display the image in its `paintComponent(...)` method override.
3. Give it decent layout manager(s) and if needed, a `getPreferredSize()` override.

Also:

- Take care that some added components, such as other JPanels, are set to be non-opaque.